# What exactly is the equivalence class of the product of ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I was reading [*So What Is Class Number 2*? by Scott T. Chapman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.04606) and it said that for two ideals of $R$, $I$ and $J$, we can say that $I\sim J$ if there is $\alpha,\beta\in R$ such that $(\alpha)I=(\beta)J$. Furthermore, we can say $[I]$ is the equivalence class of $I$, $[J]$ is the equivalence class of $J$, and $IJ=\{\Sigma_{i=1}^na_ib_j\ |\ a_i\in I\ \text{and}\ b_j\in J\}$.

Here's where I'm getting tripped up: the paper goes on to claim that $[I]+[J]=[IJ]$.

What does $[IJ]$ actually *mean*, though?

I *think* I have a good idea what $[I]$ implies. If, for example, $I$ is the set of even numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $[I]$ would be the set of all ideals $J$ such that $(\alpha)2\mathbb{Z}=(\beta)J$ for integer $\alpha$ and $\beta$. But, to the best of my knowledge, $IJ$ does not appear to be a set. It is a sum. If $I=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $J=\langle z \rangle$, then wouldn't $IJ=xz+yz$? If so, then how can you define an equivalence relation and thus an equivalence class with this? Or am I misunderstanding the definition? Help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which "this paper"?

Comment: "So What Is Class Number 2?" by Scott T. Chapman.

Comment: $IJ$ is the product of the ideals $I$ and $J$. (Read about this on M.SE.) On the equivalence classes of ideals is introduced an algebraic operation as they say: the sum of two classes is, *by definition*, the class of the product.

Comment: Btw, in your last example $I$ and $J$ are sets, not ideals.

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal and $J$ is an ideal, then the set $\{\sum a_ib_i\mid a_i\in I, b_i\in J \}$ of combinations of elements from $I$ and $J$ is an ideal, called $IJ$. It is the ideal generated by the set of products $\{ab\mid a\in I,b\in J\}$.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you, I changed it so $I$ and $J$ are actually ideals

Comment: "To my knowledge, $IJ$ does not appear to be a set." The definition of $IJ$, and its description as a set, is in your first paragraph. Did you copy and paste without reading it? It was there since your initial post.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}$, any two ideals are equivalent, so that's a rather poor place to work in. Note that if $I=a\mathbb{Z}$ and $J=b\mathbb{Z}$, then $I\sim J$ because $(b)I = (a)J=(ab)\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin my apologies, I worded it poorly - I understand that it *is* a set, but it seems like a set with only one element in it, which runs counterintuitively to my understanding of an ideal.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the set builder notation (which also has a typo in it). $\{\sum a_ib_i\mid a_i\in I, b_i\in J\}$ means $$\{x\mid \text{there exist }n,a_i,b_i\text{ such that }x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\text{ and }a_i\in I,b_i\in J\}$$

Comment: I will also note that your title line is misleading. The real issue here is that you don't understand what the product of ideals is. It really has nothing to do with the equivalence relation or equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your confusion is really about what the product of two ideals actually is. You seem to have misunderstood the "set builder" notation as denoting a single element (as per the comments). I note that you also have an undefined $j$ in the definition of $IJ$ in the first paragraph; they should both be $i$.

The notation
$$\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\,\Bigm|\, a_i\in I,b_i\in J\right\}$$
does not represent a single element of the given form, but rather *all* elements that can be written this way. This is (somewhat abusive) shorthand for
$$\left\{ x\,\Bigm|\,\text{there exist a positive integer }n\text{ and elements }a_i\in I,b_j\in J\text{ such that }x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right\}.$$

Thus, if $I=\langle x\rangle$ and $J=\langle y,z\rangle$ are ideals in (the commutative ring with unity) $R$, then $I$ consists of all elements of the form $ax$ with $a\in R$, and $J$ consists of all elements of the form $by+cz$ with $b,c\in R$. The product $IJ$ will consist of *all* sums of elements of the form $a_ix(b_iy+c_iz)$.

In general, the set of products $ab$ with $a\in I$ and $b\in B$ need not be an ideal, because it may not be closed under sums. For example, if $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z,w]$ with $I=(x,y)$ and $J=(z,w)$, then $xz$ and $yw$ are both products of elements of $I$ with elements of $J$; but $xz+yw$ cannot be expressed as a product $(ax+by)(cz+dw)$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ of an element of $I$ with an element of $J$; hence the need for taking sums of products when defining the product of the ideals.